# JPA @PrePersist @PreUpdate in interface

Tags: jpa

I wanted to use the Java 8 feature of default methods in interfaces, to automatically set a create and lastModified date in my entities.

I found the tip to implement a method annotated with @PrePersist @PreUpdate and set the values in there.

But the method isn't triggered, when saving an instance of a class implementing the interface.

I tried it by adding another method to the class which called the method in the interface and this worked.

My question now is, if this is intended behavior, that @PrePersist @PreUpdate don't work in interfaces.

Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read in the documentation of JPA that

```
/**
 * Is used to specify callback methods for the corresponding
 * lifecycle event. This annotation may be applied to methods
 * of an entity class, a mapped superclass, or a callback
 * listener class.
 *
 * @since Java Persistence 1.0
 */
@Target({METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PrePersist {
}
```

"of an entity class, a mapped superclass, or a callback" Where interface is none of these.

Interfaces **cannot be applied** to alter entities structure nor lifecycle. I do not know your specific situation but you might wanna consider Template Method pattern or reconsider your classes' hierachy.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I'll switch to a super class then. The situation is, that I didn't want to create a super class for multiple entities, that aren't really related, but should all have a createdAt and a lastModified date.